# MySQL SubQueries for multiple SUMs

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, subquery

If I need to get five+ different SUM values with similar WHERE conditions, is the best (maybe only) way to do it through one query with five subqueries?  For example, my query is:

```
SELECT user, 
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table t, table2 t2 WHERE t.table2_id = t2.id AND table2.type = 1 AND user = 1 AND date = x) AS one,
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table t, table2 t2 WHERE t.table2_id = t2.id AND table2.type = 2 AND user = 1 AND date = x) AS two, 
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table t, table2 t2 WHERE t.table2_id = t2.id AND table2.type = 3 AND user = 1 AND date = x) AS three, 
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table t, table2 t2 WHERE t.table2_id = t2.id AND table2.type = 4 AND user = 1 AND date = x) AS four, 
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table t, table2 t2 WHERE t.table2_id = t2.id AND table2.type = 5 AND user = 1 AND date = x) AS five 
FROM table 
WHERE user = 1
```

So far my queries have been very quick but I'm worried about the implication of five+ sub-queries when there's many more records.

And out of curiosity does one query like this with five sub-queries have a performance advantage / dis-advantage over five individual queries?  I was assuming it's faster because it's only one trip to the database vs 5?

EDIT: There is a table 2 of about 60 records that are used to classify the thousands of records in table 1.  Each record in table 2 is categorized by a type value of 1 - 5 (which is what I'm using to group items I want the SUM of).

Comment: For the love of [deity name], please use your real tables and real data in future questions. This dumbing down of the real situation doesn't actually get you the right answer any faster. More often than not it just gets you a wrong answer at no fault of anyone but yourself.

Comment: Yes I've noticed that.  Thanks again for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use ANSI JOINS
2. You are better writing your query in PIVOT form like the query below

**Rewritten:**

```
SELECT t.user, 
SUM(CASE table2.type WHEN 1 then amount else 0 end) As one,
SUM(CASE table2.type WHEN 2 then amount else 0 end) As two,
SUM(CASE table2.type WHEN 3 then amount else 0 end) As three,
SUM(CASE table2.type WHEN 4 then amount else 0 end) As four,
SUM(CASE table2.type WHEN 5 then amount else 0 end) As five
FROM table t
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t.table2_id = t2.id 
WHERE t.user = 1
  AND table2.type in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

I understand your query is pseudo but it has a hanging `WHERE user` without a `FROM` clause.  As for performance, the above goes through the table in one pass.  The 5x subquery form would have taken 5 passes, but should not be significantly slower if proper indexes are available.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one query to get the sum for each type:

```
SELECT 
  t2.type, 
  SUM(t.amount) 
FROM 
  table t 
INNER JOIN 
  table2 t2 
ON 
  t.table2_id = t2.id 
AND 
  t.user = 1
AND 
  t.date = x 
GROUP BY 
  t2.type
```

Comment: Thanks Dan!  Sorry, I over-simplified my query when I was asking the question and left out the important existence of a second table that I'm joining in. 'type' belongs to table 2, whereas the values I'm getting the SUM of belong to table 1. I've noted this in an edit in my question.

Comment: That doesn't change anything, still just one query with GROUP BY

Comment: Nobody should ever require that. The purpose of SQL is to retrieve data for the application, not format it some specific way for display.

Comment: `Nobody should ever require that` An very strong statement. There are reporting engines, such as Crystal, that require your data in one row. Manipulating that from rows is a bit of a non-starter. That's only the `first` thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

well.  if this just for one user, and you don't absolutely need it in that order....you could just do something like this..

```
select user, type, sum(amount)
where user = 1
and date = x
and type between (1,5)
group by user, type
```

this will give you

```
1,1,sum
1,2,sum
1,3,sum
1,4,sum
1,5,sum
```

instead of

```
1,sum1,sum2,sum3,sum4,sum5
```

This should be good enough for what you need I suspect without all that hassle.

Comment: Hey thanks Jody.  This works (and with the edit to my question after you posted this). You're right as I'm doing this for one user this should work fine. and I don't know why I didn't think of it.  Thanks again :)

Comment: It would work if you were doing it for any number of users, or all users in the table. That's why he groups by user and type.